# Merge multiple boxes into a single mesh in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a model traveling across the scene. For each position update from a data stream, a box is created to represent that position. The result is a trail that follows the model. The trail is used to help operators determine their path.
While this works fine, it can create tens of thousands of boxes.
I've tried a variety of solutions, including both merging geometry and creating a shape from the boxes, but have had little to no luck in getting decent results. The shape either doesn't match the box and merging geometries yields only a single box. What is the best way to tackle this problem?

```
//draw function for boxes
function drawNewCoord(newCoord:IPosition){
        const box = new THREE.Mesh(TRAIL_GEOMETRY, TRAIL_MATERIAL);
        box.position.set(newCoord.vector.x, newCoord.vector.y, newCoord.vector.z);
        box.setRotationFromEuler(newCoord.euler);
        return box;
}

function fuseTrail() {
        const boxes = getGroup().children;
        if(!boxes || boxes.length ===0){
            return;
        }
        const geometries:any = [];
        // @ts-ignore
        boxes.forEach((el:THREE.Mesh)=>{
           geometries.push(el.geometry)
        });
        const mergedGeometry = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries, false);
        const newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mergedGeometry, TRAIL_MATERIAL);
        props.scene.add(newMesh);
}
```

Is there a better method for creating this kind of trail than using boxes? What can I do to simplify the scenegraph?[Image of model and trail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BCOT.png)

Comment: You can't have an infinite number of boxes. You could set an upper limit and have them fade or shrink away after some time. Once they're invisible, you could recycle them and place them in a new position. Kind of like [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instan#physics_cannon_instancing), the finite number of boxes get recycled. It's more efficient to reuse meshes than to build new ones each time.

Comment: The trails are there for a particular reason, and no, they're not infinite. However, I may have to show multiple trails at the same time, meaning the number of boxes will easily be in the thousands. Making them visible/invisible or reusing them isn't exactly possible in most instances. Hence trying to find a method to unify the boxes into a single shape to represent a single trail.

Comment: You could try [InstancedBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/InstancedBufferGeometry). See here for a demo on performance: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=inst#webgl_instancing_performance

Comment: Excellent, @Marquizzo. Will give that a try. Thanks.